# Fault 500: A term with the name provided already exists with this parent.

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc

I have a problem with the use of **python wordpress-XMLRPC** when it will make a new post with the pre-existing categories, but there was an error as below:

```
Fault: <Fault 500: 'A term with the name provided already exists with this parent.'>
```

The script that I use:

```
categorys = ['cat_1', 'cat_2']
post = WordPressPost()
post.post_type = 'post'
post.terms_names = { 'post_tag': categorys, 'category': categorys }
post.title = title
post.content = content
post.post_status = 'publish'
post.thumbnail = attachment_id
client.call(posts.NewPost(post))
```

Note: "**cat_2**" is old category.

i'm use VPS server.

Please help !

Comment: do you find any solution?

Comment: hello @vaibhav I have found the solution.
you can use the script as below:
`import cgi
categorys = cgi.escape(categorys, True)
post.terms_names = { 'post_tag': categorys, 'category': categorys }`

Comment: thanks @Tarjo... i already find the solution, once again thnks

Comment: @vaibhav you're welcome !

Answer (score 0):

'terms_names' will create new category if you want to use existing category, use 'terms' and pass the id of that existing category. so instead of :

```
post.terms_names = { 'post_tag': categorys, 'category': categorys }
```

it should be

```
post.terms = { 'post_tag': 1, 'category': 2 }
```

assuming the id of the tag is 1 and category id is 2